# Is digital goods payment available for new accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

**Express Checkout Digital Goods is no longer available for new integrations. This feature remains available for merchant accounts that already have Express Checkout Digital Goods enabled.**
What does this message mean. If i opened new account i cant use this method ?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but to anyone searching it in the future (if PayPal doesn't change it's mind):

PayPal has a few points in it's products that are a little weird and fall through the cracks. This is one of them.

I too was surprised by this note, but as a recently created account (less than two months), I can tell you: it still works.

The option to enable Digital Goods it in the menu wasn't working for me... the first time I contacted Paypal's support they sent me the same instructions (which didn't worked). They said they would fix it but I found the correct link online. Just to assure you: I a friend waited for support and they enabled it for him.

I used the link below to enable Digital Goods for my account (menu option present on account ended up in the PayPal home page after some redirects): https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=acct_setup/product_selection_page&fli=true.

Good integration (and good sales)! ;]